# Complicated iOS multitouch interaction - any suggestions?

Tags: ios

I have subclassed a UIView that already handles single touches and drags. I want to enhance the interaction of this view so that, while dragging, if the user touches with a second finger (anywhere else in the view), then the system prints a message. I've made a stab at the code:

In my header file I've declared:

```
NSString *key; // This unique key identifies the first touch
```

My .m file I have:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    for (UITouch *t in touches) {
        if (key == NULL)
        {
            key = [[[NSValue valueWithPointer:t] description] copy];
        }
        if ([key isEqualToString:[[NSValue valueWithPointer:t] description]])
        {
            NSLog(@"calling parent to handle single touch");
            [super touchesBegan:[NSSet setWithObject:t] withEvent:event];
        }
        else
        {
            [self twoTouchDetected];
        }
    }
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *t in touches) {
        if ([key isEqualToString:[[NSValue valueWithPointer:t] description]])
        {
            [super touchesMoved:[NSSet setWithObject:t] withEvent:event];
        }
    }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *t in touches) {
        if ([key isEqualToString:[[NSValue valueWithPointer:t] description]])
        {
            [super touchesEnded:[NSSet setWithObject:t] withEvent:event];
            key = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there are issues with this implementation. The first time (while dragging with one finger) if I touch with the second figer, the system will register it immediately. However, the second time I touch with a second finger (while still continuing to drag with the first finger), the second finger touch does not register until the first finger is lifted up. The events from the second finger are backed up...

What is also strange is that sometimes, the parent gets called with touch data from the 2nd finger and not the 1st.

Comment: Why not using [GestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html)?

Comment: I've tried using the two fingers, one tap GestureRecognizer, but that won't work if I'm dragging with my finger. The recognizer will eat up any events before they get passed to the touchesBegin methods.

Comment: for dragging you need to use UIPanGestureRecognizer

Comment: what is the advantage of using a GestureRecognizer in this case? I might be able to recognize the single finger pan gesture (which is equivalent to the drag), but I also need to simultaneously recognize a tap whenever the user is panning. Wouldn't that require additional low level control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my code worked, but the problem was that I subclassed an object belonging to the Core Plot framework. This framework does weird things to their objects and therefore the touches were coming back in the wrong order.

I created an empty project to receive touches and everything came out great.